# Up to a scale factor

Tags: math, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am reading up on homographies and i have seen some places that it says that the homography is defined "up to a scale factor" what does this mean? Is there an upper limit for scaling the homography or what does it mean, and why?

Comment: I think http://math.stackexchange.com/ would've been a better place for this question. They have LaTeX-support! ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## General Meaning

> - ***A*** is unique up to ***Variation***
> - ***A*** is the same as ***B***  up to ***Variation***
> - ***A*** is equal to ***B*** up to ***Variation***
> - ***Statement*** up to ***Variation***

Phrases of the forms above typically mean that the ***Statement*** - the part before "up to" - is true excepting some kind of ***Variation***.  It can be thought of as meaning "...up to...but no further."

## Example

> Two points in the plane determine a line.
>   One point in the plane determines a line **up to** rotation about the point.

## Meaning with respect to Homographies

*Taken from the first section of [this document](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi07/cse252a/homography_estimation/homography_estimation.pdf):*

> ## 1. From 3D to 2D Coordinates
>
> Under homography, we can write the transformation of points in 3D from camera 1 to camera 2 as:
>
> ```
> X2 = H*X1,    X1,X2 in R^3
> ```
>
> In the image planes, using homogeneous coordinates, we have
>
> ```
> a*x1 = X1,    b*x2 = X2,    therefore b*x2 = H*a*x1
> ```
>
> This means that `x2` is equal to `H*x1` **up to** a scale (due to universal scale ambiguity).

In the next section of the same document, **Homography Estimation** is described, wherein the `z1` variable being solved for is "without loss of generality" set to `1`.  There is a whole set of solution homographies (with variation across scale), so a convention is made in this case to always choose the homograph that has universal scale `z1` set to `1`.

Comment: I get what you are saying. But then again not totally. Maybe it is my english which does not suffice. A get that you can just scale the homography and that they just choose that given scaling. But does it litteraly mean that the homography is not valid if too big a scale is chosen? And why is that?

Comment: That is not what it means. You can choose whatever scale you want. "`x2` is equal to `H*x1` **up to** a scale" means that the scale is still a free variable. -- In the example I gave, "One point in the plane determines a line **up to** rotation about the point," the meaning is that one point actually *doesn't* by itself determine a line - it just determines a line **up to** rotation (where the rotation is still a free variable).

Comment: aahh.. Now i think i get it. So it is like if you said, "it is up to the rotation to determine the line". So the homography is determined only if a scale is chosen (Makes sense since it has 8 degrees of freedom, right?)

Comment: @user1823350 Exactly. - If your question/confusion is answered/explained by my answer, please upvote and accept. :)

Comment: @TimothyShields Can I replace "up to" with "depending on" in 'line and rotation example'?

Comment: @JaeJunLEE Usually that phrase has different meaning.  For example, "The store is open or closed depending on the time of day."  It suggests a functional dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this Homography matrix, H.

```
[ h11  h12  h13 ]
[ h21  h22  h23 ]
[ h31  h32  h33 ]
```

It has 9 elements and say, I have a scale factor **s**, which is a scalar.
Now if I were to multiply the s with H, it would still be the same planar transformation.

```
    [ s*h11  s*h12  s*h13 ]
    [ s*h21  s*h22  s*h23 ]
    [ s*h31  s*h32  s*h33 ]
```

But, say, I have to do the same transformation in reverse, I would need to know just one of these new elements(e.g.: we set h33 = 1), and now the others can adjust in value to reach the same transformation.